# Transforming "what is your favorite fight scene" into an acceptable question

Tags: discussion

There are lots of great minds here. I would love to know which movie fight scene is their favorite -- through the lens of realism.

However, I know that I can't ask questions like that because, well, they indicate conversation.

I could phrase it by giving a particular example: "Is fight scene X in movie Y realistic?" but I'm pretty sure that also wouldn't work.

Stackoverflow has had a number of questions like this, such as "what was the most amusing comment you've seen in source code" -- though it has eventually been deleted (I mean after at least a year of being up) because it was, well, only amusing.

I'm guessing this site is too young to open the gate for amusing questions that break the rules, though I'd really like to be amused.

Specifically on the topic of "favorite fight scene", transformed into an acceptable question for MA.SE - what do you think? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. It's entirely subjective and very chatty. I have been on forums where they had "favorite fight scene" threads and they eventually generated hundreds of posts and spawned off new threads. I don't think that kind of clutter is something we want on here.

Comment: Those type of questions don't help anyone. Remember that the purpose of Stack Exchange is to provide good and useful information for other people. Asking what people's favorite *X* is doesn't serve that purpose.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was talking about (although re-reading it, apparently that bit was only in my head, it didn't come out in writing). I don't want to spawn off a lot of dumb questions, but I know there is room to have fun. There has to be.

Comment: @Trevoke Well, do you exactly have an actual question to ask then? If you do, skip over this conceptual type of question and we'll see how to work on it within the scope. Note that questions about movies, comics, and science fiction are considered off-topic according to the [faq] so figure out how to go from there. Also see the ["Gorilla vs. Shark" blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).